# Name of the generalization of quadtree and octree?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, algorithms, approximation, trees

What is the name of the equivalent of quadtrees and octrees in n-dimension ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the generalization of quadrants and octants is the orthant, I'd have thought "orthtree" would make sense.  But I only turned up one or two papers using this term.  The term "hyperoctree" seems to be far more common in the literature.

Answer (score 2):

Note that quadtree/octree-type structures tend not to be used as one goes up much further in dimension because of the classic 'combinatorial explosion' of the splitting factor; a node that needs to be split will yield $2^d$ children even if many of them are empty.  Instead, once the dimension goes up (and often even in two and three dimensions) the more common structure is a binary tree where each internal node corresponds to an axis-orthogonal split (though these splits typically don't have to partition their volume evenly).  These are known as [*k-d trees*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree); you should be able to find quite a bit of information about them out there.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, k-d trees are not a generalization of quadtrees/octrees, but it may be what you are looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-d_tree

Comment: No, K-d tree obeys a different logic, and I am speaking of the generalization of quadtree/octree...

Comment: +1 for a relevant answer. A k-d tree, although fundamentally a different data structure, solves the same problem as an octree, but is "generalized" as in it works in any k-dimensional space.

Comment: From most general to most specific : BSP tree -> KD tree -> octree

Answer (score 0):

I have seen the generalization of octrees being called KD-tree-pyramids. A K-dimensional tree-pyramid (KD-TP) is a full tree where each node represents a K-dimensional subspace.

The most common instances of KD-TP are Full Binary Trees($K=1$), Quadtrees($K=2$), Octrees ($K=3$) and Hexadecatrees ($K=4$).

As Steven mentioned beyond 4D they don´t scale well and kd-trees are used the most.